# C question: no warning?

Tags: c++, c

```
main()
{
  printf("Hello World.");
}
```

Why does no warning is produced in gcc compiler even though we declare main() with return  type 'int'

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because you're not using the -Wall flag.  When you do, you should get:

```
foo.c:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’
foo.c: In function ‘main’:
foo.c:1: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘printf’
foo.c:1: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
foo.c:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
```

Comment: i mam not talking about other warnngs .. i just want to know why there is no warning like "return type of main is int" even if i compile using gcc -Wall

Comment: @Grv: In fact, the *first* line is the warning you're looking for, though the last line also refers to `main()`.

Answer (score 2):

Did you forget to compile with warnings enabled:

```
gcc -Wall ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your main function return nothing. so modify in void main().
Usually is:

```
int main() { printf("Hello world"); return 0; }
```

Comment: a small comment: I have learned from Gman here at SO that even if it is *int main(){ .. }* return 0; isn't needed. Not sure if it produces warnings or whatnot :)

Answer (score 0):

No warning is produced because that's legal ANSI C89. Functions without a specified return type are implicitly assumed to return `int`.

If you want to compile as C89, but be warned about using implicit int, you should pass either `-Wimplicit-int` as a command line argument (or `-Wall`, which enables that warning, along with a number of others).

If you want to compile as C99, you should pass `-std=c99` and `-pedantic-errors`, which will cause the compiler to issue an error if you use implicit int.