# Forcing GCC 4.x to treat -Wreturn-type as an error without enabling -Werror?

Tags: c++, gcc, return-value, gcc-warning, gcc4

Suppose we have the following code:

```
#if !defined(__cplusplus)
#  error This file should be compiled as C++
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

//#define USE_CXX_CLASS
#ifdef USE_CXX_CLASS
class SomeClass
{
public:
    SomeClass() {}
    ~SomeClass() {}
    std::string GetSomeString()
    {
        // case #1
    }
};
#endif // USE_CXX_CLASS

int foo()
{
    // case #2
}

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    (void)argc;
    (void)argv;
#ifdef USE_CXX_CLASS
    SomeClass someInstance;
    someInstance.GetSomeString();
#endif // USE_CXX_CLASS
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

And suppose that it were to be compiled the C++ compiler (and not the C compiler) from GCC version 4.2.1 with the options `-Wreturn-type -Werror=return-type`. If the above code is compiled as is without first uncommenting the `//#define USE_CXX_CLASS` line above, then you will see a warning **but no error**:

```
.../gcc-4.2.1/bin/g++   -g    -fPIC -Wreturn-type -Werror=return-type    test.cpp -c -o test.o
test.cpp: In function 'int foo()':
test.cpp:26: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
```

But if the `//#define USE_CXX_CLASS` line is uncommented, then the warning **is** treated as an error:

```
.../gcc-4.2.1/bin/g++   -g    -fPIC -Wreturn-type -Werror=return-type    test.cpp -c -o test.o
test.cpp: In member function 'std::string SomeClass::GetSomeString()':
test.cpp:18: error: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
gmake: *** [test.o] Error 1
```

Yes, one is a non-member function (case #2), and the other is a C++ function (case #1). IMO, that should not matter. I want both conditions treated as an error, and I don't want to add `-Werror` or `-Wall` at this point in time (probably will do so later, but that is out of scope of this question).

My sub-questions are:

1. Is there some GCC switch that I am missing that should work? (No I do not want to use `#pragma`'s.)
2. Is this a bug that has been addressed in a more recent version of GCC?

For reference, I have already poured through other similar questions already, including the following:

- [Why does flowing off the end of a non-void function without returning a value not produce a compiler error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610030/why-can-you-return-from-a-non-void-function-without-returning-a-value-without-pro)
- [C question: no warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558610/c-question-no-warning)
- [Is a return statement mandatory for C++ functions that do not return void?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784075/is-a-return-statement-mandatory-for-c-functions-that-do-not-return-void)

Comment: did you found a solution to this @bgoodr

Comment: Not yet. It might be the case that this is actually a bug fixed in more recent releases of the compiler, but since I do not have an option to upgrade the compiler at this point in time, I'm going to just wait until we do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been fixed, it works well with `g++ 9.3`: both member functions and free functions are treated as error with `-Wall -Werror=return-type`

Answer (score 1):

I do see an error even w/o the USE_CXX_CLASS flag. i.e. g++ is consistent with the error for both class member functions and non member functions.
g++ (GCC) 4.4.3 20100127 (Red Hat 4.4.3-4)

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me that what you need is a shell script wrapper around gcc.

- Name it something like `gcc-wrapper` and `g++-wrapper`.
- In your Makefile set CC and CXX to the wrappers.
- Have the wrapper invoke GCC and pipe its output to another program which will search for your desired warning strings.
- Have the search program exit with an error when it finds the warning.

Comment: Thanks Zan. Actually what I was mainly looking for is an answer to sub-question #1. I don't want to get into the business of carrying around wrappers to hack around what I believe GCC itself should support. I'm starting to conclude that this is a bug (or missing feature) in GCC itself.